# I am trying to transfer a range of data from each sheet in a workbook in to summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a summary sheet with specific sheet names in a specific column if the sheet names in the existing workbook apart from summary sheet, match with the tabulated values then specific cells will have to be copied from all sheets into corresponding rows of summary sheet. How can I solve this. In the attached image I want to transfer data from AY56, AZ56 & BA56 cell number of each sheet containing data to columns, F,G & H where the sheetnames match with values below column A in the summary sheet

```
Sub Summary_LPI()

  Dim wsX As Worksheet, wsS As Worksheet
  Dim strSheetsToExclude As String, strArr() As String

  Set wsS = Worksheets("Summary")

  strSheetsToExclude = "Sheet2"

  strArr = Split(strSheetsToExclude, ",")
  For Each wsX In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If Not wsX Is wsS _
  Then
    wsX.Range("AY56").CurrentRegion.Copy
    If IsEmpty(wsS.Range("F2")) Then
        wsS.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
       End If
    End If
 Next
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: "How can I solve this." Solve what? Please describe the problem with your code precisely.

Comment: Here's some info on how to create a [mcve].